# Error: "invalid access of mutable storage in an 'isolated' function" for anonymous function

Tags: ballerina

I am getting the compilation error `invalid access of mutable storage in an 'isolated' function` when attempting to update an array using an anonymous function with the `forEach` iterator.

The code:

```
isolated function searchEmailThread() returns string {
    gmail:MailThread[] threads = [];

    stream<gmail:MailThread,error?>|error threadList = gmail->listThreads(filter = {includeSpamTrash: false, labelIds: ["INBOX"]});
        
    if (threadList is stream<gmail:MailThread,error?>) {  
        error? threadItr = threadList.forEach(isolated function (gmail:MailThread thread) {
            lock {
                threads.push(thread);
            }
        }); 
        return threads.toString();
    } else {
        return "Failed to list threads";
    }
}
```

The variable `gmail:MailThread[] threads` cannot be defined as isolated as well. Is there an alternative approach to obtain and return the mail threads from the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`threads` is a captured variable for the argument function passed to `forEach` and for that function to be `isolated`, `threads` should either be `final` and have a type that is a subtype of `readonly|isolated object {}` or it should be an `isolated` variable.

Since none of that is possible here, you could rewrite this to use a [query action](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/query-actions/) (or a [query expression](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/#query-expressions)).

```
error? res = from gmail:MailThread thread in threadList 
do {
    threads.push(thread);
};
```

Also related to https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/602

Only module-level variables can be defined as `isolated` variables at the moment (related [spec issue](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/630)).